# LTSpice Colpitts oscillator: How can I compute a priori the output amplitude?

Tags: ltspice, oscillator

I have simulated this LC oscillator with a MOSFET and it works.

How can I compute the amplitude of the output oscillating signal, theoretically?

[image: LC Colpitts Oscillators]

[image: Mosfet data]

Comment: One minor comment: if you give L and W you often don't need to provide the rest of the areas and perimeters, as they are calculated based on L and W. If you do, there could be cases when your values and LTspice's will clash due to a difference of decimals E.g. you may write 24p but LTspice might calculate it as 23.9999...p. It will not count as an error (the simulation will run) but the error log will pop up, promptly.

Comment: You are not expecting especially little! The amplitude will grow as high as possible before the effective gain drops (due the distortion) below the amount needed to compensate the feedback path attenuation. If you do not want to find it by simulating numerically nor by  building a test circuit you need the machinery of non-linear circuit analysis and that's something substantially more complex than analyzing linear circuits. A way out: Insert an AGC circuit which is manageable and reduces the gain steeply above a certain level before the mosfet amp starts to distort severely.

Answer (score 5):

> *How can I compute a priori the output amplitude?*

You can't; well not to any degree of reasonable accuracy. If it were a BJT Colpitts oscillator then it can be a tad more accurate. Think about how much variation there might be in the gate-source threshold voltage of any MOSFET - this will have a large impact on the variations seen in the output amplitude of a simple common source amplifier let alone an oscillator whose output amplitude is roughly held within a range of values due to non-linearities in the device as well as the threshold voltage nuances.

As with any sine wave oscillator, the basic formulas describe the frequency of oscillation but not the amplitude. Simple single transistor sine wave oscillators rely on distortion to limit the output amplitude and hence, these circuits are a bit hit-and-miss.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to dead-bug or board this with a socket, buy 1pc of the same FET from every distributor (different batches), run them all, and arrive at a mean and deviation.

Answer (score 3):

For each "linear" (better: quasi-linear) oscillator the output amplitude is determined by (a) the excess gain (above the theoretical unity loop gain requirement) and (b) the non-linearity (intentional or non-intentional) within the loop.

Remember the nice sentence: Each linear oscillator requires a certain (small) amount of non-linearity.

Only when both quantities as mentioned under (a) and (b) are well known you can make a good guess about the expected amplitude - provided that the first harmonic analysis may be applied (sufficient damping of higher harmonics due to the selective frequency characteristic of the feedback circuit).